# Java Applet - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, applet, indexoutofboundsexception

OK so I am getting an ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException. I don't know why.

Here's my code:

```
/**
Tile Generator
Programmer: Dan J.
Thanks to: g00se, pbl.
Started May 23, 2010
**/

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.Applet;

public class tileGen extends Applet implements KeyListener  {


    Image[] tiles; // tile arrays
    Image player; // player image
    int x, y, px, py, tx, ty; // x tile - y tile // player x - player y // tile x - tile y
    boolean left, right, down, up, canMove; // is true?
    int[][] board; // row tiles for ultimate mapping experience!
    final int NUM_TILES = 33; // how many tiles are we implementing?
    Label lx, ly; // to see where we are!
    private static int BLOCKED = 28;

    int lastX, lastY, row, col;

  public void init() {

    board = loadBoard();

    tiles = new Image[NUM_TILES];
    for(int i = 0;i < NUM_TILES;i++) {
        tiles[i] = getImage(getClass().getResource(String.format("tiles/t%d.png", i)));
    }
        board[2][2] = BLOCKED;
        player = getImage(getClass().getResource("player.png")); // our player
        addKeyListener(this);
        canMove = true;
        px = 0;
        py = 0;
        lastX = 0;
        lastY= 0;
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

if (blocked(lastX,lastY) == true) {
    System.out.println("You were JUST on a BLOCKED tile!");
}

int x1 = lastX = lastX + 1;
int y1 = lastY;
       System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++\n(" +x1+","+y1+") " + blocked(x1,y1) + "\n++++++++++++++++++++++++");

        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            left = true;
            px = px - 32;
            lastX = lastX - 1;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            right = true;
            px = px + 32;
            lastX = lastX + 1;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            down = true;
            py = py + 32;
            lastY = lastY + 1;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            up = true;
            py = py - 32;
            lastY = lastY - 1;
        }



        repaint();
    }
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){} // ignore
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){} // ignore

  public void paint(Graphics g) {


        for (row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
            for (col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++) {
                int index = board[row][col];
                g.drawImage(tiles[index], 32 * col, 32 * row, this);

            }
        }
        System.out.println("X: " + lastX + "\nY: " + lastY + "\n=============================\n");

System.out.println("Blocked tile?: " +blocked(lastX,lastY) + " ("+lastX + ","+lastY+")");
        g.drawImage(player, px, py, this);
    } // end paint method

     public void update(Graphics g)
     {
          paint(g);
     }

    public int[][] loadBoard() {
        int[][] board = {
                { 2,2,24,24,24,24,24,1,3,0,0,0 },
                { 2,2,24,23,23,23,24,1,3,0,0,0 },
                { 1,1,24,23,23,23,24,1,3,3,3,3 },
                { 1,1,24,24,23,24,24,1,1,1,1,1 },
                { 1,1,1,1,7,1,1,1,1,1,3,3 },
                { 5,1,1,1,7,7,7,7,7,1,3,3 },
                { 6,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,7,7,7,3 },
                { 6,1,3,1,3,1,3,1,1,1,7,3 }
            };
    return board;
    }

    public boolean blocked(int tx, int ty) {

            return board[tx][ty] == BLOCKED;
        }

} // end whole thing
```

The thing is when I go to the red brick at `board[2][2]`... I go there. Then I go up... then I TRY go to back down but that error pops up. Also when I go to the right 8 squares... I ALSO get that error.

ALSO, pretend my 2d map is split into FOUR squares... well square one is the top left... if I go ANYWHERE else ... I get that error.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

update: i found the culprit! It's the lastX and lastY updates when I press the key! But I still can't figure out to fix this array out of bounds! :(

Here is the error:
`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
 8
        at tileGen.blocked(tileGen.java:111)
        at tileGen.paint(tileGen.java:86)
        at tileGen.update(tileGen.java:92)
        at sun.awt.RepaintArea.updateComponent(RepaintArea.java:239)
        at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paint(RepaintArea.java:216)
        at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.handleEvent(WComponentPeer.java:306)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4706)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThre
ad.java:269)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.
java:184)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThre
ad.java:174)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)`

```
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)

    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)</code>
```

Comment: You need to tell us where which line you're getting the error from etc.

Comment: OK I updated the main question.

Comment: `int x1 = lastX = lastX + 1;` why are you doing `lastX = lastX + 1` here? It looks like the exception happens in `blocked` when `tx == 8`.

Comment: I'm also unsure exactly where the error is coming from, but you might want to ensure that you've got all your coordinate systems figured out. 2D arrays are `array[row][col]`, and graphics in Java is `(col, row)` with the origin at the upper left and the y-axis upside-down. I see that your call to `Graphics.drawImage` correctly orders `col` and `row`, but couldn't quite make out whether every other `x` and `y` do the right thing.

Comment: That's funny.. I can't go past board[-1][-1] such as board[-2][-2] :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, an [`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) is thrown when there's an attempt to access an array element at an index that is out of bounds.

The following snippet shows some scenarios (independent of each other) where `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` are thrown:

```
    // 1
    int[] x = new int[5];
    x[-1] = 0; // ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

    // 2
    int[] x = new int[5];
    x[5] = 0; // ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5

    // 3
    int[][] table = new int[3][3];
    table[0][10] = 0; // ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10

    // 4
    int[][] table = new int[3][3];
    table[-10][10] = 0; // ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -10

    // 5
    int[][][][] whoa = new int[0][0][0][0];
    whoa[0][-1][-2][-3] = 42; // ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

    // 6
    int[][][][] whoa = new int[1][2][3][4];
    whoa[0][1][2][-1] = 42; // ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
```

Where and how this happens in your applet is unclear, but rest assured that it happens for the right reason: you've illegally tried to access an array element at an invalid index, and since arrays are bound-checked at run-time in Java, the run-time exception is raised.

You may want to bring out the debugger to see how the invalid index was evaluated, but if nothing else, lots of `System.out.println` wherever you're mutating the index and wherever you're about to access an array element can help locate the bug.

---

#### Additional tips:

Instead of:

```
lastX = lastX + 1;
lastY = lastY - 1;
```

You can do:

```
lastX++;
lastY--;
```

This is called the "post-increment" and "post-decrement" operators. Used judiciously, it can improve readability.

#### References

- [JLS 15.14.2 Postfix increment operator](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.14.2)
- [JLS 15.14.3 Postfix decrement operator](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.14.3)

Comment: Additional Additional Tip: Java classes start with uppercase letters.

Comment: Also, indent code properly. Please.

Comment: I can't go past board[-1][-1] such as board[-2][-2] :(

Comment: @Dan: I don't understand what you're saying, but array indices must be non-negative (http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/arrays.html#10.4)

Comment: I got it! I figured out the problem. I was re-defining lastX and lastY + 1 on each. :P

Comment: "Generally speaking, an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown when there's an attempt to access an array element at an index that is out of bounds." - captain obvious